# Managing tailored styles in CMS platform

Tags: css, content-management-system, saas

I'm working on a SaaS platform which will have tailored styles for user accounts. Our current system uses YAML to write individual stylesheets.

As account volume grows is this a suitable approach? Is there a database solution for dynamic styles or similar?

Good reference would be to [Tumblr.com](http://tumblr.com). - Does anyone know how they store and manage styles?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can put the CSS file in the user's personal folder after you [compress it somehow](http://www.csscompressor.com/). Your webserver will take care of the rest.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would avoid a bunch of CSS files. Thoughts?

Comment: Short of creating a column for every CSS property in your database and looking it up every time a user requests a page, I can't think of something else.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your input @rath